# Request: please re-open my question

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260768/cannot-create-jdbc-driver-of-class-for-connect-url-null-java-lang-nullpoint was closed as "Not a real question" without any comments from the users who voted to close it: Gamecat is Toon Krijthe, AShelly, and casperOne♦.

I edited it shortly thereafter and contacted those users to request they re-open my question. I received no response from them.

After much experimentation, piecing together the results of tons of googling over several weeks -- as no one result on SO or anywhere else seemed to solve the problem -- I finally found the reasons behind the issues I detailed.  As the question is closed, I posted my detailed solution as comments on the question.

The issues and solutions I detailed would be of great use to SO users as just about every SO and Google search result usually ended with a *shrug* as no one seemed to know how to solve this issue.

Please re-open my question so I can post my detailed solution as an answer instead of as a comment.

Comment: You flagged it only after posting this meta question. -1 minutes is not a lot of time to wait for a moderator response.

Comment: OT, but please don't start your questions with "Help!". Unnecessary at best, annoying at worst.

Comment: If you want to put the answer on SO you first need to have a good question.  The fact that you've found an answer doesn't change the fact that the question ought to be closed.  You should edit the question into something appropriate for the site before it can be reopened and answered.

Comment: FYI, how did you contact the users in the close list?  That's borderline harassment.  I surely hope you're exaggerating here.  Also, no need to post who closed it here, as it's shown quite clearly when a question is closed.

Comment: I think that "please re-open my question" isn't a good question too, you should have asked what was wrong with your SO question.

Comment: However you still can make it a good question if you include the code.

Comment: OK, it's been re-opened, move quick and answer it.

Comment: I have received no message from so how can you expect that I give a reaction?

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe That explains why you have not been responding to my telepathic messages. Hmm, I shall conquer the world through other means.

Comment: @Bart, Drat, conquering the world was my ambition. I'll have to stick to programming irritaing bugs for the rest of my life.

Answer (score 19):

Stack Overflow is **not** a program debugger.

If you have a specific problem you want to post, then post away, but if it a general: "Here is my program and stack trace, what is wrong??" type of question, **that is not** a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your questions don't get closed you should include more details.

In future post the code that is causing the problems, otherwise no one will bother answering to the question.

It's like if you ask to a doctor what medicine you should take without explaining the symptoms.

**EDIT**

I see that you are trying to make jdbc work, so you haven't written the Java code that you should post. In your case I would suggest to make another question asking how to correctly install jdbc, otherwise if you just ask for debug that's too localized.

That's what you're looking for:

[Install a JDBC driver from the vendor of your database](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html#step3).

If you have a mysql database that should be pretty easy: look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Comment: -1, this is not very helpful...the OP *did in fact* post the code that was causing the problem.

Comment: This is Java, even if he hasn't included it in the tags. His problem indeed is a NullPointerException. He has posted the Java stacktrace, but he hasn't posted any Java code.

Comment: Well he hasn't written that code, but instead he should ask how to install jdbc correctly. This is just a stacktrace, he is asking how to debug it and it may be too localized.

Comment: He posted the configuration information and the stacktrace generated by the configuration. That sounds like all the code needed. I don't disagree that this is Too Localized, but I disagree that the OP didn't add enough code.

Comment: Sixlettervariables thank you for the thumbs up.

@RamyAlZuhouri If you look at my question and what I discovered was the solution to the problem -- well, you can't now that some moderator decided to delete it -- no Java code was involved.  It was both an unnecessary Context node in server.xml and a incorrectly configured ResourceLink.  The stack trace was throwing a NPE with a blank jdbc.  Based upon my googling, NOBODY on the Internet pointed to either one as a cause.  Why don't people want this info published?

Comment: The way you're asked it, that made the difference.